Trying to add list inside 2D list in a function in python
I am new to python and wasn't able to understand why this code isn't working as required.
Below is the code :
class Solution:
    def subsets(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        self.res = []
        def solve(i,temp):
            if(i==len(nums)):
                #print(temp)
                self.res.append(temp)
                return
            temp.append(nums[i])
            solve(i+1,temp)
            temp.pop()
            solve(i+1,temp)

        solve(0,[])
        return self.res

When I print the value of temp inside the solve function I receive this :
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[1]
[2, 3]
[2]
[3]
[]

but when I'm adding the temp inside my res list, temp is always added as []. Final Value of res is like this :
[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]

